# How to dereference a temporary pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

Here is a piece of C++ code that confuses me.

For a variable var, (int*)(&var) can get var's address and *(int*)(&var) can get var's value. However, if there is a pointer ptr point to var, WHY *(int*)(&ptr) cannot get var's address???

```
int var = 2;
cout << "var' address and value: " << &var << " " << var << endl;
cout << (int*)(&var) << endl;
cout << *(int*)(&var) << endl;
cout << (int*)*(int*)(&var) << endl;


int *ptr = &var;
cout << "ptr's address： " << &ptr << endl;
cout << (int*)(&ptr) << endl;
cout << *(int*)(&ptr) << endl;//NOT var's address, WHY?
cout << (int*)*(int*)(&ptr) << endl; //var's address,
cout << *(int*)*(int*)(&ptr) << endl; //var's value,
```

Comment: Part of the reason that confuses you is because significant portions of it make no sense whatsoever. `(int*)*(int*)(&ptr)` ?? So, acquire a `int**`, cast it to `int*`, dereference it to `int`, then cast that to `int*`.  The chaos that will result when this runs on a platform where `int` and `void*` are not the same size.

Answer (score 0):

WhozCraig is write, it's just because you are casting a pointer to a `int`. If you are running on a 32bits machine, this may work fine (because pointers are on 8 bytes and `int` too), even if not recommended at all. But on 64bits machine it won't, as pointers (`int*`, `void*`) use 8 bytes, while `int` uses 4 bytes.

To illustrate, I'm using a 64bits machine, When I run your program as posted (using `int`), I get:

```
var' address and value: 0x7ffd12c3dbd4 2
0x7ffd12c3dbd4
2
0x2
ptr's address： 0x7ffd12c3dbd8
0x7ffd12c3dbd8
314825684
0x12c3dbd4
Segmentation fault
```

When I replace all `int` by `size_t` (which is 64bits on my machine, and will be 32bits on a 32bits machine):

```
size_t var = 2;
cout << "var' address and value: " << &var << " " << var << endl;
cout << (size_t*)(&var) << endl;
cout << *(size_t*)(&var) << endl;
cout << (size_t*)*(size_t*)(&var) << endl;

size_t *ptr = &var;
cout << "ptr's address： " << &ptr << endl;
cout << (size_t*)(&ptr) << endl;
cout << *(size_t*)(&ptr) << endl;// var's address, OK
cout << (size_t*)*(size_t*)(&ptr) << endl; //var's address,
cout << *(size_t*)*(size_t*)(&ptr) << endl; //var's value, OK
```

I get:

```
var' address and value: 0x7ffd5c258de0 2
0x7ffd5c258de0
2
0x2
ptr's address： 0x7ffd5c258de8
0x7ffd5c258de8
140726149418464
0x7ffd5c258de0
2
```

No more segmentation fault, and `*(size_t*)(&ptr)` reports `140726149418464` which is equal to `0x7ffd5c258de0`.

Edit: See Marian Spanik comment, there may be other appropriate types than `size_t`. But what's sure, is that `int` is not appropriate.

Comment: I think that even `size_t` might be too small and the correct type is `intptr_t`.

Comment: Interesting, never heard of that. I'll mention this in my post